# How to reset the location of multiple buttons in a form when one button is moved

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I'm making a drag and drop game for my A level computing coursework. My drag and drop works fine, but I have 6 buttons/options and I want to reset the locations on the other 5 buttons when I move on the 1 button. The 6 buttons are named btnAnswer1, btnAnswer2, btnAnswer3, etc.

I already tried to search for a solution, and it still doesn't work

```cs
bool isDragged = false;
Point ptOffset;
private void buttonMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    Button theButton = (Button)sender;
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        isDragged = true;
        Point ptStartPosition = theButton.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        ptOffset = new Point();
        ptOffset.X = theButton.Location.X - ptStartPosition.X;
        ptOffset.Y = theButton.Location.Y - ptStartPosition.Y;
    } else {
        isDragged = false;
    }
}

private void buttonMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    Button theButton = (Button)sender;
    if (isDragged) {
        Point newPoint = theButton.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        newPoint.Offset(ptOffset);
        theButton.Location = newPoint;
    }
}

private void buttonMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    Button theButton = (Button)sender;
    isDragged = false;

    if ((theButton.Location.X >= 190 && theButton.Location.X <= 468) && (theButton.Location.Y >= 42 && theButton.Location.Y <= 236)) {
        answerText = theButton.Text;
        if (answerText == RandomQuestion[0].CorrectAnswerPosition) {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct Answer");
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Wrong Answer");
     // disableDragDrop();
    }
}
```

I don't know how to reset the locations of the other 5 buttons when I move 1 button.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the button off postion this way

```
        yourButton.Location = new Point(50, 50); //x and y cordinate off position
```

You should rest your 5 buttons positions in the method where you move 1 button with my method.  Hope this helps.